# Old pop-up notifications in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, notification-area

Windows 10 pop-up notifications are terrible and slow. Is there a way to replace them with old Windows 7/8 notifications? I'm pretty sure it's possible since I did pretty much the same thing for sound mixer.

Windows 10 notification:

[image: Windows 10 notification]

Windows 8 notification:

[image: Windows 8 notification]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Winaero posted a hack](http://winaero.com/blog/enable-balloon-notifications-in-windows-10-using-a-registry-tweak/) to enable the old Balloon Tips again:

1. Open Registry Editor.
2. Go to the following Registry key: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer`
3. Create a new 32-bit DWORD value named `EnableLegacyBalloonNotifications` and set its value data to 1.

[image]

4. restart the PC.

Now you should have the old popups again.

That the Ballon Tipps is show in the left side is a bug, which is fixed since [Build 10586.420 (KB3163018)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3163018). Here is the [changelog](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/update-history-windows-10):

> Fixed an issue that was causing balloon tip notifications to always
>   appear on the upper left side of the screen.

To get the update just check for Windows updates in the settings app.

Comment: Thanks. But unfortunately a problem occurred, balloon tips now appear in the left upper corner of the screen.

Comment: post a picture of the issue. I haven't tried this setting

Comment: Here's what happens with notifications from Last.fm Scrobbler http://i.imgur.com/M0IeHiC.jpg
And seems like Telegram has Win10 style pop-ups, although I'm not sure, maybe it's Telegram style pop-ups http://i.imgur.com/UQyC5lz.jpg

Comment: if software alls the toasts o it's own, it  can't be converted. Only software that used BallonTipps which were converted to the Toast notificatons show again as the old one. I have no idea why it is on the left.

Comment: @Rooxie this is a bug, which is now fixed by Microsoft. try this new update or wait for the next patchday to get it

Comment: @Rooxie KB3163018 is now out as offical update. Now your issue should be fixed that ballon tipps appear on the left side

Comment: @Rooxie have you tried the new update? Is the bollon tipp now shown correctly?

Comment: It's ok now. I re-installed Windows and then updated it, though.

Comment: nice to hear this

Comment: if the update works, mark the reply (green check mark) as answer to "close" the question