# Getting repetitive historic notifications while playing more no of audio files

Tags: windows-10, audio, notifications, user-folders

I have a question which is related to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1080540/old-pop-up-notifications-in-windows-10) but also has increased replay of historical notifications.So its nowhere duplicate to that.
**Operating system**-Windows10  Home Personal Laptop

- I am playing 30 songs from E:\Songs\English by manually pressing enter to each and every track i want to listen.As i press enter on the selected track it opens in vlc media player to which I get notifications.
- After listening to 20 tracks I see a notification on the
  Notification icon regarding the track being played.I click on it after clicking it all 20 tracks historical notifications keep popping up one after the other automatically without me closing them.

---

The problem is that these historical notification pop-ups which come afterwards one after the other without me closing them is an unexpected behavior.How do I stop such absurd behavior of notifications.It keeps appearing every time no matter how many times i restart/shut down